# How to check, how often someone gave input in a Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I mean by that question, how do i check how often someone gave input in a:
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Im am beginner, so don't wonder (if its possible a dumb question :)
I've already tried something like this:
Thx for help! :)

```
int test1 = 0;
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (input < test1) // I don't know how i can let check the computer, how many inputs the 
                                                                        user already did
    {
          // ACTION
    }
```

Comment: There is a specific reason of why do you want to do the conversion to Int32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another aproach will be to create another method which will encapsulate and add the functionality to keep and increase the counter. So even if you are calling `Console.ReadLine()` from outside it is increasing the counter inside `public YourMethodName()`.

```
public YourMethodName()
{
    var inputCount = 0;
    var test1 = 5;
    
    while (inputCount < test1)
    {
        _consoleReadLine(ref inputCount);
        //ACTION

        //Notice that inputCount must increase to dont create an infinite loop
    }
}

private string _consoleReadLine(ref int counter)
{
    counter++;
    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Notice: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` gives `System.FormatException` when no numeric characters inserted.

`while` loop will not be reachable because `inputCount` will never be lower than `test1` in this example, adjust variables.

If it does not solve your problem, please detail the question more deeply with more information to help us give you a better answer.

**EDIT**

If you want to do it for the *higher lower game* this may be what you need. I am sharing both ways with array and with list.

**Array**

```
        var inputLimit = 5;
        var inputs = new int[inputLimit];

        for(var i = 0; i < inputLimit; i++)
        {
            var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.SetValue(input, i);
        }
            
        // inputs array have all values introduced by user
        // LOGIC CODE
```

**List**

```
        var inputLimit = 5;
        var inputs = new List<int>();

        for(var i = 0; i < inputLimit; i++)
        {
            var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.Add(input);
        }
            
        // inputs array have all values
        // LOGIC CODE
```

Asks for more clarifications if needed and mark as answer if it  solves this problem.

Comment: im trying to code a higher lower game & i wanna do, if someone gives more than (for example) 5 inputs, the program does not accept any other trys (i think its able with return)

Comment: @s0lid Setting `var test1 = 5;` and call `_consoleReadLine` inside while once the user will leave the while stopping the call to `_consoleReadLine` method. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use another variable to keep track of this. For example:

```
var inputCount = 0;
var test1 = 0;
while(inputCount < test1)
{
    var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    inputCount++;
}
```

This will increase `inputCount` by 1 each time they input something in the console.

Comment: There are two errors, if test1 is lower than inputCount you will never reach Console.ReadLine(), so no way to test in this case. The second one is that Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) gives a System.FormatException.

Comment: I'm aware. The OP is obviously new to programming. I am simply answering the question

Comment: All the code in here I copied from the OP's post except for the while loop (because this doesn't work without a loop somewhere) and `inputCount` because, well, it's the answer to their question.

Comment: I agree that your logic is fine and answer the question but he may encounter other problems trying your answer since you did not advice him.

Comment: It's not my place to fix issues outside of the scope of the question. If they run into them, they can ask or search for a solution.